How to unlist a column of `distribution` or `vctr` in R?
Q: How do I appropriately unlist a data frame column of type distribution in R?
In the example below, generate() gives me the shape of data I want. But I have to use forecast() (generate() seems to have some issues with combination and/or hierarchical forecasts), which gives me a column of distribution objects. I'm not quite sure how to work with these. I provide my attempt, involving map(), pivot_longer(). But this just can't be the right way, right?
library(fpp3)

# data example from "Forecasting Principles and Practice", Ch 5.5
# https://otexts.com/fpp3/prediction-intervals.html

gafa_stock |>
  filter(Symbol == "GOOG", year(Date) >= 2015) |>
  mutate(day = row_number()) |>
  update_tsibble(index = day, regular = TRUE) ->
  google_stock

google_stock |> filter(year(Date) == 2015) -> google_2015

google_2015 %>% model(NAIVE(Close)) -> fit

# I like this sort of output, which is easy for me to plot
fit %>% generate(h = 30, times = 5, bootstrap = TRUE) -> gen.sim
# # A tsibble: 150 x 6 [1]
# # Key:       Symbol, .model, .rep [5]
# Symbol .model       .rep    day .innov  .sim
# <chr>  <chr>        <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 GOOG   NAIVE(Close) 1       253 -0.204  759.
# 2 GOOG   NAIVE(Close) 1       254 -0.984  758.
# 3 GOOG   NAIVE(Close) 1       255 -3.55   754.
# 4 GOOG   NAIVE(Close) 1       256  2.21   756.

# This output is trickier for me, producing a `distribution` column
fit %>% forecast(h = 30, times = 5, bootstrap = TRUE) -> fcs.sim
# # A fable: 30 x 5 [1]
# # Key:     Symbol, .model [1]
# Symbol .model         day     Close .mean
# <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>    <dist> <dbl>
# 1 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   253 sample[5]  752.
# 2 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   254 sample[5]  752.
# 3 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   255 sample[5]  751.
# 4 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   256 sample[5]  769.

# This is my attempt to unlist the `distribution` column `Close`
# It works, but this can't be the right way to do it.
fcs.sim %>% 
  pull(Close) %>% 
  map(unlist) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  bind_cols(fcs.sim) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=x1:x5) %>% 
  mutate(name=str_remove(name,'^x')) %>% 
  rename(.rep=name) ->
  fcs.sim.2.gen.sim
# # A tsibble: 150 x 5 [1]
# # Key:       Symbol, .model, .rep [5]
# Symbol .model       .rep    day  .sim
# <chr>  <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 GOOG   NAIVE(Close) 1       253  752.
# 2 GOOG   NAIVE(Close) 1       254  758.
# 3 GOOG   NAIVE(Close) 1       255  761.
# 4 GOOG   NAIVE(Close) 1       256  750.


What are you trying to accomplish? The package returns a distribution because that is what is needed in computing prediction intervals, forecast accuracy statistics, etc. It's hard to provide any help without knowing your aim.

Trying to accomplish a couple things: 1) simulation path plots which are easily generated here with gen.sim %>% autoplot(.sim), as you did in 5.5. But, generate() is not working for me on combined forecasts and/or hierarchically reconciled forecasts (top_down(), bottom_up(), middle_out()). Only forecast() is working for me in these cases. But fcs.sim %>% autoplot(Close) produces an error. So I need to find a way to pull out the sample distribution elements.

@RobHyndman also, 2) construct accumulated series, so something like fcs.sim %>% mutate(x1.cmm = cumsum(x1)), where x1 is the 1st .rep. fcs.sim %>% mutate(Close.cmm = cumsum(Close)) would accumulate over the .rep for a fixed day, which is not what I'm looking for.

The distribution isn't a data frame column, but instead a vctr.
The distributional package allows you to extract the parameters of a distribution (in this case your generated samples) with distributional::parameters().
Generally speaking (not just for distributions) you can obtain the data inside a vctr with vec_data().

Example:
library(fpp3)
#> -- Attaching packages ---------------------------------------------- fpp3 0.5 --
#> v tibble      3.2.1          v tsibble     1.1.4     
#> v dplyr       1.1.4          v tsibbledata 0.4.1     
#> v tidyr       1.3.1          v feasts      0.3.2     
#> v lubridate   1.9.3          v fable       0.3.3.9000
#> v ggplot2     3.5.0          v fabletools  0.4.1
#> -- Conflicts ------------------------------------------------- fpp3_conflicts --
#> x lubridate::date()    masks base::date()
#> x dplyr::filter()      masks stats::filter()
#> x tsibble::intersect() masks base::intersect()
#> x tsibble::interval()  masks lubridate::interval()
#> x dplyr::lag()         masks stats::lag()
#> x tsibble::setdiff()   masks base::setdiff()
#> x tsibble::union()     masks base::union()

gafa_stock |>
  filter(Symbol == "GOOG", year(Date) >= 2015) |>
  mutate(day = row_number()) |>
  update_tsibble(index = day, regular = TRUE) ->
  google_stock

google_stock |> filter(year(Date) == 2015) -> google_2015

google_2015 %>% model(NAIVE(Close)) -> fit
fit %>% forecast(h = 30, times = 5, bootstrap = TRUE) -> fcs.sim

You can then mutate the parameters of the distribution to get it in a list format
fcs.sim |> 
  mutate(distributional::parameters(Close))
#> # A fable: 30 x 6 [1]
#> # Key:     Symbol, .model [1]
#>    Symbol .model         day     Close .mean x        
#>    <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>    <dist> <dbl> <list>   
#>  1 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   253 sample[5]  756. <dbl [5]>
#>  2 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   254 sample[5]  751. <dbl [5]>
#>  3 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   255 sample[5]  746. <dbl [5]>
#>  4 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   256 sample[5]  741. <dbl [5]>
#>  5 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   257 sample[5]  732. <dbl [5]>
#>  6 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   258 sample[5]  739. <dbl [5]>
#>  7 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   259 sample[5]  748. <dbl [5]>
#>  8 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   260 sample[5]  745. <dbl [5]>
#>  9 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   261 sample[5]  750. <dbl [5]>
#> 10 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   262 sample[5]  766. <dbl [5]>
#> # i 20 more rows

And unnest them if you like.
fcs.sim |> 
  mutate(distributional::parameters(Close)) |> 
  unnest(x)
#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#>    Symbol .model         day     Close .mean     x
#>    <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>    <dist> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   253 sample[5]  756.  760.
#>  2 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   253 sample[5]  756.  765.
#>  3 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   253 sample[5]  756.  758.
#>  4 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   253 sample[5]  756.  762.
#>  5 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   253 sample[5]  756.  735.
#>  6 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   254 sample[5]  751.  756.
#>  7 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   254 sample[5]  751.  770.
#>  8 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   254 sample[5]  751.  755.
#>  9 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   254 sample[5]  751.  758.
#> 10 GOOG   NAIVE(Close)   254 sample[5]  751.  714.
#> # i 140 more rows

Created on 2024-05-06 with reprex v2.0.2

Is something like the following what you had in mind? fcs.sim %>% pull(Close) %>% parameters() %>% pull(x) %>% map(\(.x) data.frame(t(.x))) %>% bind_rows(). Still seems like I'm doing something wrong here.

I've added an example of how you can do this with dplyr/tidyr instead.

That works! I added %>% group_by(Symbol, .model, day) %>% mutate(.b=row_number()) %>% to identify the bootstrap sample.
